# How many uses do Crab Pots have?

Tags: stardew-valley

I understand that you need to fill crab pots daily. Do they degrade at all besides that? If so, how long will they last? Or will they last forever and you can eventually create a Crab Pot empire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find any indication that there's a way for it to disintegrate.  There's code to update the CrabPot object each day (e.g. to have it catch something if the conditions are right), but there's nothing in that code to "age" the crab pot or otherwise get it closer to being destroyed.

As far as I can see, crab pots last forever.

(Source: Snooping in the source code with a decompiler)